# how does wav2vec2 quantize continuous speech deterministically

Tags: signal-processing, k-means, speech, quantization

I am trying to understand the [`wav2vec2`](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.11477) paper better. I understand that the raw signal is passed through a `feature encoder` which outputs *latent speech representation* which is *continuous*. Then it is passed through a `quantization module` which outputs *discrete labels* to be passed to the context layer.

Now my confusion is that, since the quantization module uses `Gumbel vector quantizer or k-means quantizer` which are both **non-deterministic**, isn't the discrete labels different on each run for the same sample? And if that's the case how is the wav2vec2 model working?